# check authentication on Laravel schedule

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, schedule

I have schedule like this

```
$schedule->call(function () {
     $mial->getMail(Auth::user()->id);
})->everyMinute();
```

show me this error

> In Kernel.php line 37:
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

When I run this command show me this error again

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    echo Auth::user()->id;
})->everyMinute();
```

I need to be check authentication.

Comment: You cannot use authentication in laravel console commands

Comment: Session is maintains in browsers only

Comment: I know but what do am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that because a user doesn't run the scheduled command, so `auth()->user()` object will always be `null`.

To fix this, you can save user ID in DB and fetch the data on scheduled command execution.

Comment: Ok but I don't know how is login? can you more explain

Answer (score 3):

You cannot check `auth` via the command line as a command does not have any information about the session. It is not concerned with HTTP / a browser at all